# Elasticsearch.Net Nuget Packagage

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nest

I am having an issue with the Elasticsearch.Net Nuget package. 
I am not very familiar with the .Net environment and more with development, and after i followed the quick start for Nest (http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/quick-start.html) i cannot install the Elasticsearch.Net package but the Nest Nuget is installed. 
The error i am getting is:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Elasticsearch.Net'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Elasticsearch.Net
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the documentation has been updated, the initial release of the Elasticsearch.Net 1.0 client has not been published on NuGet yet. NEST is available on NuGet as you found, but is still at version 0.12.0. Version 1.0 of Elasticsearch.Net and NEST should be released shortly. In the meantime, you can continue to use NEST 0.12.0. The 1.0 documentation is still pretty accurate for most of the basic operations and querying. Alternately, you could get the latest source for Elasticsearch.Net and NEST from the [Elasticsearch.Net GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net) site, compile it locally and manually reference it your project.

Comment: The ElasticSearch.Net and Nest 1.0 Beta1 clients are now available via NuGet. Read this ElasticSearch blog post for more details about their release. http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/introducing-elasticsearch-net-nest-1-0-0-beta1/